# Удаление повторяющихся элементов из коллекции

Tags: c#

Если есть коллекция элементов, которые могут повторяться, например, `IEnumerable<int>`, то как проще всего получить из этой коллекции новую коллекцию, в которой каждый элемент первоначальной коллекции будет присутствовать только один раз? Как сделать отбор в цикле, я понимаю, но это наверняка не самый простой метод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сделать Set из списка, например, используйте [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438.aspx). А можно сразу хранить в нём данные, если порядок не важен. Отбор в цикле это самый неэффективный способ. И не очень нагляден.

Answer (score 3):

Все куда проще, у IEnumerable<t> есть метод Distinct, он делает то, что Вам нужно.

Информация: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348436.aspx

Answer (score 1):

С алгоритмической точки зрения есть два эффективных способа:

1. Складывать элементы в хэшмапу
2. Отсортировать, пробежаться и «схлопнуть» повторяющиеся.

Самый простой с точки зрения написания вариант, действительно, через множество. Но тут уже эффективность будет зависеть от реализации множества стандартной библиотекой.

Comment: В названии HashSet уже содержится ответ на вопрос об алгоритме: внутри скорее всего "урезанная" хэшмапа.

Comment: А, ну я название класса-то не знал :). С таким названием, очевидно, да, хэшмапа. Но тогда надо не забывать думать о памяти.

Comment: Если хешмапа нормально сделана, то сильного перерасхода быть не должно. Да, и правда, я ссылку дал на HashSet, а написал просто Set для простоты.